# Как исправить видимость записей в архиве?

Tags: wordpress

на странице archive.php я использую такой код

```
<?php if(!is_user_logged_in()): ?>
            <h4>Доступ к записям автора ограничен.</h4>
          <h5>Вы должны <a href="/loginto">войти</a>, чтобы просмотреть записи.</h5>
    </div>
<?php else : ?>
остальной код страницы
<?php endif; ?>
```

но из одной категории записи желательно бы открыть и для гостей без авторизации. как это осуществить?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Примерно так:

```
<?php
global $cat;
$allowed_cat = 01; // ID разрешённной категории

if( ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) && ( $allowed_cat !== $cat) ):
?>
        <h4>Доступ к записям автора ограничен.</h4>
        <h5>Вы должны <a href="/loginto">войти</a>, чтобы просмотреть записи.</h5>
    </div>
<?php else : ?>
остальной код страницы
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: вышло такое "Страница недоступна
Сайт ...... пока не может обработать этот запрос"

Comment: Ошибка 500 - это синтаксис или другая ошибка php. В ответе была опечатка, попробуйте еще раз.

Comment: Хотелось бы услышать минусовщиков - код сами пробовали тестировать? Я-то попробовал, все работает, см. комментарии к другому ответу.

Comment: У меня тема другая и категория имеет id 257 поэтому не работало именно с этим id. не обратила внимания на изменения, то теперь код сработал. ошибки нет. спасибо

Comment: а как подобное сделать и на главной index.php? потому что такой уже не срабатывает вариант. на моей странице index.php и singple.php  точно такой же код использовала для скрытия всех записей. категорию где фото надо вывести как открытую а прочие записи блога скрыть от гостей

Answer (score 0):

Код в коментарии выше не должен работать, так как он расчитан на таксономию и одно ещё примечание: категории и не только начинаются с числа 1 и далее, то есть при 01, 02, 03, и т.д. у вас будет ошибка синтаксиса, так как php понимает как строку `01`, отсюда и отдает ошибку. Чтоб узнать, какую категорию (для конкретного типа поста) нужно блокировать, просто зайдите в панель администрирования на редактирование категории, вверху в ссылке на страницу будет параметр `tag_ID=2`, где `2` ID нашей категории.

А сейчас, представим, что вам нужно показывать гостю не одну, а несколько категорий? Как быть в таком случае, так как с предыдущего примера у нас позволяется показ только одной?

Рекомендую Вам пример моего решения:

```
$allow = [1,2,3]; // Масиив с разрешенными категориями, у нас для примера 1, 2, 3
$error = in_array(get_queried_object()->term_id, $allow); // Проверяем есть ли текущая категория в разрешенном массиве значений
if((!is_user_logged_in())&&($error==false)){
// Пользыватель не залогинен и находится в закблокированой категории
} else if(!is_user_logged_in()&&($error==true)){
// Пользыватель не залогинен и находится в разрешенной категории
} else if(is_user_logged_in()){
// Остальной код, добавлена проверка в условии, залогинен ли пользыватель, так как рушится логика работы(проверки статуса пользывателя)
}
```

Также, изменив в примере `get_queried_object()->term_id` параметр `term_id` на другой, например `name` `slug` `count`, для упрощения понимания, можно проверять не только по ID категории, а по ее ссылке, имени, количестве постов.

Comment: Насчет ошибки синтаксиса - это вы очень сильно погорячились. И близко нет ничего подобного. Преобразованеи типов вы понимаете неправильно. Код рабочий. На снимке - полный код archive.php в дочерней теме test от twentyseventeen. Результат можете посмотреть у меня на тестовом сайте: http://test.kagg.eu/category/uncategorized/  Как легко догадаться, категория Uncategorized имеет ID=1.

Comment: Кроме того, это неверно, что код расчитан на таксономию. Вы откуда это взяли? global $cat - это переменная, содержащая номер текущей категории, а никакой не таксономии.

Comment: Забыл снимок из phpStorm приложить https://monosnap.com/file/D7hlmg3mlIYIEaSNntwTQD757weZ35

Comment: если я правильно указала, то такой код также не работает в блоге с моими id категорий 1 и 217